# How to check mathematically that a number has its first n digits greater than 0

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, binary

For example, assume we have number $a = 111$. Clearly, each of the $n = 3$ least significant digits is greater than $0$ so this number is acceptable (*return $1$*).

However, consider the number $a = 310$. The least significant digit is $0$ so this number is not acceptable (*return $0$*).

More specifically, I want to express this function in a single math formula using math notations. The ultimate purpose of this is to express it as **exactly** one constraint in a Linear Programming formulation.

For instance, one approach would be to compare the number to an $n$-digit number composed of 1s. For instance, if $n = 3$, we can compare the number to $111$. This can be trivially expressed as $a < 111$.

However, **this doesn't work** because $200$ is accepted since it's greater than $111$, but not all digits are greater than $0$.

**Constraints for the formula**:

- No multiplication of the digits.
- No bitwise operations.

Comment: *First* is an ambiguous term. You should say first from the right, or better, the least significant digits.

Comment: For programming this is quite easy (assuming no additional constraints) do $\mod x$ if the result is bigger then $0$ divide the number by $x$ and repeat the procedure $n$ times or until the result is equal to $0$.

Comment: I don't think you are giving us enough information for a useful answer.

Comment: @kingW3: except that modulo is much more costly than multiplications and bitwise operations, and on some architectures even unavailable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree but none mentioned that the solution had to be optimized.

Comment: @kingW3: this is a reson why the question makes little sense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for your comments. The question indeed made little sense so I have updated it to reflect more context. The main objective of this formula is to use it in linear programming so I can neither use multiplication nor I can use more than one formula to check the number feasibility.

Comment: The acceptance/rejection sets have a complex shape and are disconnected. I don't see any hope of a single constraint in a purely linear setting.

Answer (score 0):

Saying "in base $x$" means that you have the expansion of the number as a string of digits. So you see the zeroes and the question doesn't make much sense.

If the number is available in another base (to make this question meaningful), such as binary, you don't have much more resort than converting to the base $x$.

This involves modulo operations, i.e. worse than what you forbid.

---

**Update, using the newer explanations:**

For, say, $n=3$, the "forbidden" numbers are

$$1000k+\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,110,120,130\cdots,200,201,202,\cdots210,220,230\cdots,\cdots990\}.$$

This set would require dozens of inequalities to be represented by linear constraints.

Comment: I read the question as follows: Given $a$ as a number, when do the first digits of $a$ in base $x$ are all nonzero? This does not imply that the digits are known.

Comment: @lhf: but how is $a$ "given" ? In any case, my answer addresses this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is a very good point that I should have addressed. $a$ is given as a number with no extra information. For instance, in linear programming, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), exactly one constraint should check if this number has each least significant $n$-digits greater than 0

Comment: @YvesDaoust I removed the ambiguity about base $x$. Assume it's not given as it doesn't really add much to the question. Thanks.